# Is there a formula to determine if a ballon on the of deep water rises up?

Tags: pressure, buoyancy

Imagine a balloon (again) that finds itself on the bottom of a mass deep water. The balloon is filled with air. The deep mass of water finds itself on a heavy (w.r.t. Earth) planet.

Initial, the balloon stays put (on the bottom)

After it's not stayed put anymore (it's let loose), what will happen and why?

It's clear that pressure and temperature (or other pairs of state variables) have to do with it. Maybe the water could freeze.

Is there a mathematical formula that can answer this question?

I searched and thought about the solution, but couldn't find it. But after reading the first answer it's as clear as water. The air inside the balloon is lighter than the surrounding water (if the air inside the balloon is not frozen by the high pressure, in which case I'm not sure if the ice density scales with pressure). The first answer made me realize that, so apparently, I had thought about it too little.

Comment: Sounds like a puzzle or quiz question, I voted to close. And I would choose 1).

Comment: Why did you vote to close? Is this off-topic, just because it sounds like a quiz question. In that case, you could vote to close **all** questions.

Comment: As I marked, because of the policy on homework questions. This is not about a physics concept, you are asking us to do your "work". https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: 1) This is not a homework question (I don't do homework questions), 2) The question is about physics (or a physical concept, as you call it abstractly). 3) I don't ask you to do my work (I just wasn't able to find an answer or find it out myself), but 3 points it would do for sure (or a 4-th thing maybe). I just ask which and why.

Comment: Please remove these last three comments.

Comment: Why have there two (contrasting) answers been given?

Comment: According to [this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Hnjn7kVQ0HgJ:itc.gsw.edu/faculty/bcarter/ISCI/Balloon.pdf) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aTDsB4uPmQc) balloon attached to the bottom of the sea, will be not only compressed, but **stretched too**,- because of water pressure differences, up until the point if that stretching force becomes large enough - balloon may be teared apart to peaces by gravity, leaving question of loosening it meaningless.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Can water pressure ever be high enough to trap gas bubbles or keep them from surfacing?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70176/can-water-pressure-ever-be-high-enough-to-trap-gas-bubbles-or-keep-them-from-sur)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the immense pressure, the balloon will shrink in size. Once let loose, the balloon will start accelerating by quite a bit (somewhat both 2 and 3) and will eventually attain terminal velocity at a point. Then onwards, the balloon will rise at the same pace.

Comment: No, it could never accelerate rapidly. It would almost immediately attain a terminal velocity, which might change when the balloon expends. But I doubt that it would rise.

Comment: The initial acceleration will still be large due to the huge net force upwards.

Comment: There would be no huge force. The density of the air would be of the same order of magnitude as that of the water, maybe a bit less, maybe a bit larger, I don't know. But the rubber is probably more dense and should weigh it down.

Answer (score -1):

At room temperature and 1 atmosphere pressure air weighs 1.3 g/l. The pressure will increase the density by a factor of 1099, making it denser than water. Obviously the ideal gas law no longer applies and also the air can no longer be gaseous but actually is solid. Solid air is heavier than water at 1 atmosphere but the density of water at that depth has increased as well and exceeds this. The balloon will slowly rise. If the air density remains lower at all depths, it will eventually reach the surface.

Comment: The ratio in density will be less than 1000 because at such densities the general gas law does not apply. But there is also the weight of the rubber of the balloon. I really doubt that it will rise.

Comment: As I said, the ideal gas law does not longer apply and even the air will become solid. Why this answer gets negative appraisal escapes me, by the way. So much negativity these days.

Comment: I did not vote it down, but I doubt the air would be solid when water is liquid.

Comment: @Pieter I did not read the paper but her is an $N_2$ phase diagram: https://images.app.goo.gl/ADFj2C59BaZKfZXF6 . It implies that N2 is solid at the relevant pressure and temperature. I would not bet my life on it so it could be liquid as well. Gaseous is impossible .

Comment: To me, that phase diagram suggests that N$_2$ would be a supercritical fluid at high pressure and temperatures above $0$ °C.

Comment: Yes, definitely in the supercritical fluid region

Comment: The NIST says that N2 at 4 C and 100 MPa has a density just under 0.6 g/ml. So it should float.

Comment: @Dale That depends on the relative amounts of nitrogen (or air) and rubber. Maybe 1 ml of compressed air and 1 cm³ of rubber would sink?

Comment: @my2cts If you make a little edit I can give you an upvote.

Comment: Please continue in chats

Comment: @Pieter most balloons are made of latex and the density of latex rubber ranges from 0.910 to 0.925 g/ml according to this vitaldoc.lgm.gov.my:8060/vital/access/services/Download/vital1:23797/ARTICLE so the rubber floats and the contents float. It should float.